# How to Access a Wifi Device Through a Switch

Tags: networking, network-drive

Here's the situation...

I have 3 desktop Win PC's ("A", "B" and "C") connected to a Switch (TP-Link 8 Gigaport Switch).  Also connected to my switch is the cable company's router, and I have a 100 foot Ethernet wire to the middle of my house where there is a wireless router.

This works great - home automation stuff + cell phone connect to wireless router, A, B, & C can talk to each other (share files, remote desktop, shared printer, etc).  Life was grand.

Then I bought a MS Surface.  I can't get the Surface to "see" A, B & C, and they can't see the Surface.  I assume it is because the wireless router OR the Switch won't share outside their walls.  How do I do that?

I'm a programmer, not a network guy (obviously) so dumb it down for me!  Thanks!

Comment: Wow a negative for a legitimate question ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume broadcasts or multicasts are used to "see" other hosts.

If your wireless router is configured in NAT mode then broadcasts won't be forwarded between your wired and wireless network.

Try configuring your wireless router to operate in bridged mode which will allow broadcasts to be forwarded between the wired and wireless networks. This will allow discovery to "see" hosts on the other part of the network.

As your cable router will be acting as a DHCP server you should disable the DHCP server on you wireless router when it is operating in bridged mode.